# Detect page scaling

Tags: javascript, html, scale

I'm writing a web page with Javascript. I have to somehow work with my DIV layer properties refer to page scaling.

How can I do this? You can find the example at [apple](http://www.apple.com/) page. Try to scale it and look at top menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should use EM's for all you dimensions, so all you elements will scale (when font-size only scaling is enabled). So you can measure the font-size on elements to know it the text-zoom was modified or not.

There is no way to know if the page was zoomed by the browser or not (as i wrote, only if the text zoom is used)

here is a workaroud: it will only work if the font-size is zoomed
http://jsfiddle.net/gGdAq/4/

Basically if the width in Pixel of the element your interested in, is not the base font size * the width in em the page was zoomed.

Maybe this question helps:
[Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I thought scaling meant re-sizing the window. You meant zooming in and out, my bad.

---

The top menu on the apple site is a fixed with and will not scale with the re-sizing of the browser window. If you wanted to have that feature, you would have to assign a:

```
div {
    width: %; //percentage value you want
    min-width: px; //the minimum pixel value you want
}
```

This way it expands and decreases with the page width, yet maintains a min width for readability

Also, using `em` as a `font-size` will help keep the text size dynamic as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this (or similar) behavior on virtually any site. Havent tested it in any other browsers but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993309/detect-zoom-in-firefox/5976415#5976415) is my answer to the same question concerning firefox.

Comment: as i wrote in my Answer, this only works when text-zoom only is enabled